# Getting an error that I need to use middleware, but I have already applied middleware

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

Okay so I am following a tutorial, and I'm a beginner. This is my first experience with Redux.

This is the error I've been getting when it should be displaying the home screen of my webpage.

> Actions must be plain objects. Instead, the actual type was: 'string'. You may need to add middleware to your store setup to handle dispatching other values, such as 'redux-thunk' to handle dispatching functions. See https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-4-store#middleware and https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-6-async-logic#using-the-redux-thunk-middleware for examples.

I have been searching everywhere but it looks to me like I applied thunk correctly. I'm hoping someone more experienced will be able to spot my mistake. Thank you.

HomeScreen.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import { listProducts } from '../actions/productActions.js';

import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

function HomeScreen() {

    
    const productList = useSelector(state => state.productList);
    const { products, loading, error} = productList;
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(listProducts());
        return () => {
            //
        };
    }, [])

    return loading? <div>Loading...</div> :
    error? <div>{error}</div>:
    <ul className="products">
    {
      products.map(product =>
        <li key={product._id}>
            <div className="product">
                <Link to={'/product/' + product._id}>
                    <img className="product-image" src={product.image} alt="product" />
                </Link>
                <div className="product-name">
                    <Link to={'/product/' + product._id}>{product.name}</Link>
                </div>
                <div className="product-brand">{product.brand}</div>
                <div className="product-price">${product.price}</div>
                <div className="product-rating">{product.rating} Stars ({product.numReviews} Reviews)</div>
            </div>
        </li>)
    }
  </ul>
}
export default HomeScreen;
```

store.js

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { productListReducer } from './reducers/productReducers.js';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import * as compose from 'lodash.flowright';

const initialState = {};
const reducer = combineReducers({
    productList: productListReducer,
})

const composeEnhancer = window.__REDUXDEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(reducer, initialState, composeEnhancer(applyMiddleware(thunk)));
export default store;
```

productActions.js

```
import { PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL, PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST, PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS } from "../constants/productconstants.js";
import axios from "axios";

const listProducts = () => async (dispatch) => {

    try {
        dispatch(PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST);
        const {data} = await axios.get("/api/products");
        dispatch({type: PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS, payload: data});
    }
    catch (error) {
        dispatch({type: PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL, payload:error.message});
    }
}

export {listProducts};
```

productReducers.js

```
import { PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL, PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST, PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS } from "../constants/productconstants";

function productListReducer(state= {products: [] }, action) {

    switch (action.type) {
        case PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST:
            return {loading:true};
        case PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS:
            return {loading:false, products: action.payload};
        case PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL:
            return {loading:false, error: action.payload};
        default: 
            return state;
    }
}

export { productListReducer }
```

Comment: Just FYI I will recommend using reduxjs toolkit now, if you are learning. It makes redux easy to work with. Also, Check the productsActions the error I belive is pointing to this  dispatch(PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST` appears to be a string. You *cannot* dispatch a string by itself - only action objects.  Actions are *always* objects that have a `type` field inside, like `{type: 'counter/incremented'}`.

That said, you *should* be using [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux) to write your Redux code.  Redux Toolkit will simplify all of the Redux store setup and reducer logic you've shown.